# SimpleMatrix getMatrix().getData() issue

Tags: java, matrix, ejml

I am using EJML SimpleMatrix and I get the error `The method getData() is undefined for the type Matrix` when I try to return a double[] using the following code:

```
double[] test = result.getMatrix().getData();
```

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I needed to import DMatrixRMaj and cast the .getMatrix() to a DMatrixRMaj then use .getData(). See code below

```
double[] ret = ((DMatrixRMaj)result.getMatrix()).getData();
```